# How to initialise a member array of class in the constructor?

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the following:

```
class sig
{
public:

int p_list[4];
}

sig :: sig()
{
p_list[4] = {A, B, C, D};
}
```

I get an error

> missing expression in the constructor.

So how do I initilalise an array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++11 only:

```
class sig
{
    int p_list[4];
    sig() : p_list { 1, 2, 3, 4 }   {   }
};
```

Pre-11 it was not possible to initialize arrays other than automatic and static ones at block scope or static ones at namespace scope.

Comment: I have C++10. So I had to do it hard way. Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: Is sig(): declaring the constructor?   This answer would be more helpful for beginners if it matched the basic layout of the question, so we can see how the constructor works.   What is the empty `{}` ?

Comment: And why is there no `;` after the initializer?

Comment: Assuming c++11 is available, is there a slick way to initialize the array if the values are not known at compile time? I could do `sig(float p[4]) : p_list{p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]}` but that seems clumsy.  or maybe just memcpy?

Answer (score 8):

> So how do I initilalise an array?

Using the normal initialiser list syntax:

```
sig::sig() : p_list{1, 2, 3, 4}
{ }
```

Note, this only works in C++11. Before that, you need to use a `boost::array` an initialise it inside a function.

Answer (score 5):

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 initialization, then you have to assign each field separatly:

```
p_list[0] = A;
p_list[1] = B;
p_list[2] = C;
p_list[3] = D;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your current compiler doesn't yet support C++11, you can initialize the vector contents using standard algorithms and functors:

```
class sig
{
public:
    sig()
    {
        struct Functor
        {
            Functor() : value(0) {};
            int operator ()() { return value++; };
            int value;
        };
        std::generate(p_list, p_list + 4, Functor());
    }

    int p_list[4];
};
```

Previous snippet example [here](http://ideone.com/q5Yai).

Yes, is kind of ugly (at least, it looks ugly for me) and doesn't do the work at compile time; but it does the work that you need in the constructor.

If you need some other kind of initialization (initialization with even/odd numbers, initialization with random values, start with anoter value, etc...) you only need to change the Functor, and this is the only advantage of this ugly approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise the array members like this using c++11 compiler using -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 option

```
struct student {
        private :
                int marks[5];
        public :
                char name[30];
                int rollno;
                student(int arr[], const char *name, int rno):marks{arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]}{
                        strcpy(this->name, name);
                        this->rollno = rno;
                }
                void printInfo() {
                        cout <<"Name : "<<this->name<<endl;
                        cout <<"Roll No : "<<this->rollno<<endl;
                        for(int i=0; i< 5; i++ ) {
                                cout <<"marks : "<<marks[i]<<endl;
                        }
                }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int arr[] = {40,50,55,60,46};
        //this dynamic array passing is possible in c++11 so use option -std=c++11
        struct student s1(new int[5]{40, 50, 55, 60, 46}, "Mayur", 56);
        //can't access the private variable
        //cout <<"Mark1 : "<<s1.marks[0]<<endl;
        s1.printInfo();`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
p_list[4] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
```