# OOP Bubble sort C++ program

Tags: c++, oop

I am getting these errors 
Compiler Error C3867 (((( 'func': function call missing argument list; use '&func' to create a pointer to member ))))

nothing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cuzmo
{
private:
    int array[1000];
    int n;

public:
    Cuzmo ()
    {
        int array[] = { 95, 45, 48, 98, 485, 65, 54, 478, 1, 2325 };
        int n = sizeof (array) / sizeof (array[0]);
    }

    void printArray (int* array, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

void bubbleSort (int* array, int n)
{
    bool swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int temp;

    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - j; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
};

int main ()
{
    Cuzmo sort;

cout << "Before Bubble Sort :" << Cuzmo::printArray << endl;

cout << Cuzmo::bubbleSort << endl;

cout << "After Bubble Sort :" << Cuzmo::printArray << endl;

return (0);
}
```

I am getting these errors 
Compiler Error C3867 (((( 'func': function call missing argument list; use '&func' to create a pointer to member ))))

Comment: Your constructor does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `array` is a local variable in the constructor. It no longer exists after the constructor exits. Same with `n` these have nothing to do with the class members of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you simply forgot the parentheses after your function calls?
Try `Cuzmo::printArray()` and `Cuzmo::bubbleSort()`.
Also, you may want to use std::vector instead of a fixed-size int array (so that you loop over your actual entries rather than 10000 mostly uninitialised values) and look into std::swap.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you call a function `f` with no arguments:

```
f;
```

This is how you do it:

```
f();
```

Furthermore, you're trying to send the return value of `bubbleSort()` to `cout`, but there is no such value as the function has `void` return type.

In fact, the same is true of your `printArray()` function: it already does the printing, and there is no result value to send to `cout`.

Try:

```
cout << "Before Bubble Sort :";
Cuzmo::printArray();
cout << endl;

Cuzmo::bubbleSort();

cout << "After Bubble Sort :";
Cuzmo::printArray();
cout << endl;
```

The other problem is that you are declaring and initialising a local variable `array` in your constructor; this variable has nothing to do with the member.

- [How to initialise a member array of class in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11610338/560648)

The same is true of your variable `n`. You keep redeclaring new, local variables that *shadow* the member variables.