# Bubble sort C++ OOP

Tags: c++

Please I want to improve this code by using the private section and if there is other better way to write this code with. Please help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cuzmo
{

//private:


public:
    int array[10] = { 95, 45, 48, 98, 485, 65, 54, 478, 1, 2325 };
    int n;

    Cuzmo ()
    {
        array[10];
        n = sizeof (array) / sizeof (array[0]);
    }

    void printArray (int* array, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            cout << array[i] << endl;
    }

    void bubbleSort (int* array, int n)
    {
        bool swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        int temp;

        while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - j; ++i)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Cuzmo sort;

    cout << "Before Bubble Sort :" << endl ;
    sort.printArray (sort.array, sort.n);
    cout << endl;

    sort.bubbleSort (sort.array, sort.n);

    cout << "After Bubble Sort :" << endl;
    sort.printArray (sort.array, sort.n);
    cout << endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to improve something with using the "private section"? What ever this is meant to be... I think you want to add some private members or methods?

Comment: `array[10];` in your constructor is undefined behavior and serves no purpose.

Comment: Why is Cuzmo a class, and why is it holding those. hard-coded values? I don't think you even need a class here. And please take the small amount of time to properly edit your question so it's readable.

Comment: [This looks like the same homework assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58269106/oop-bubble-sort-c-program)

Comment: There was a change in the constructor from the previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Cuzmo
{

private:
    std::vector<int> m_array { 95, 45, 48, 98, 485, 65, 54, 478, 1, 2325 };


public:
    Cuzmo () = default;

    void printArray()
    {
        for (auto entry : m_array )
            std::cout << entry << "\n";
    }

    void bubbleSort()
    {
        bool swapped {true};
        int j {0};

        while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i {j}; i < m_array.size()-1; ++i)
            {
                if (m_array[i] > m_array[i + 1])
                {
                    std::swap( m_array[i], m_array[i+1] );
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
            ++j;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    Cuzmo sort;

    std::cout << "Before Bubble Sort :" << "\n";
    sort.printArray();
    std::cout << "\n";

    sort.bubbleSort();

    std::cout << "After Bubble Sort :" << "\n";
    sort.printArray();
    std::cout << "\n";

    return (0);
}
```