# How to initialize whole array to single element in class constructor in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Hi I am looking to initalize whole array to single element in constructor of class.I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610338/how-to-initialise-a-member-array-of-class-in-the-constructor) solution but I am getting this errror.

```cpp
1>C:\Users\Ahmad Mustafa Anis\source\repos\ciruclar queue\Source.cpp(8,8): error C2590: 'sig': only a constructor can have a base/member initializer list
1>Done building project "ciruclar queue.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

My code is

```cpp
class CircularQueue {
public:
    int dataItems[10];
    sig() : dataItems{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} { }

};
```

I have Visual Studio 2019, I guess c++ version in it is cpp17. If there is someway I can add a constructor and assign whole array to 0 without for loop or explicitly element by element, like this constructor

```cpp
CircularQueue() {
        dataItems = { 0 };
    }
```

or this one

```cpp
CircularQueue() {
        dataItems =  0 ;
    }
```

In both case my error is

`error C3863: array type 'int [10]' is not assignable`

Comment: the method `sig()` is not a Constructor.
You can only use initializer lists with Constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize all values with `0`

```
CircularQueue() : dataItems{} {}
```

Or,

```
CircularQueue() : dataItems{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} {}
```

If the array is too long, you can do this. It is not *initializing*. It's *assigning* after initialization.

```
CircularQueue() {
    std::fill(dataItems, dataItems+10, 3); //3 for example
}
```

Comment: Its probably more safe to use `dataItems+sizeof(dataItems)`.

Comment: @Flo No `sizeof(dataItems)` is `40`.

Comment: This works. I need to assign 0 so the first technique is useful for me. Thanks.

Comment: @김선달 True, It would need to be divided by `sizeof(int)`

Comment: `fill` can use `begin`, `end`, so if the size is changed, it only needs to be done in one place.